# How to update FCM token

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, appdelegate

I am having the same issue where the key gets generated 2 times.

As stated here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6813

My question is how I can always keep my token updated with the Messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken: callback?

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {

      let deviceToken:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        print("Device token: ", deviceToken) 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last comment from a contributor on github says:

> This is expected. We recently discover that sometimes, the APNS token is collected from Apple with a slight delay after first token request was issued, so client has to issue a second token request with the apns token mapping in it. So you are getting that scenario which is why you are getting the token callback twice.
> It wasn't happening before because there was a bug that the second
> token request is not triggered and was recently fixed in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/6669.
> This should not affect your work as long as you always keep your token updated with the Messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken: callback."(charlotteliang)

So you should be fine as long as you update the token on every didReceiveRegistrationToken call. You can do that as the documentation describes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#monitor-token-refresh.

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
  print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")

  let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
  NotificationCenter.default.post(
    name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
    object: nil,
    userInfo: dataDict
  )
  // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
  // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
```

Comment: It worked with that!